# How can I read an AWS S3 File with Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I tried to read a file from AWS S3 to my java code:

```
  File file = new File("s3n://mybucket/myfile.txt");
  FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Then I got an error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: s3n:/mybucket/myfile.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
```

Is there a way to open/read a file from AWS S3? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The 'File' class from Java doesn't understand that S3 exists. [Here's an example of reading a file from the AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingJava.html):

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());        
S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
InputStream objectData = object.getObjectContent();
// Process the objectData stream.
objectData.close();
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a corresponding jar (for those classes) in maven that I can use?

Comment: yes- the [aws java sdk](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk). There are also [installation instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-setup.html).

Comment: @tedder42, is there any API to process the data if the object content is an email. I want to get the email content, from, to etc

Comment: @edwiser ask as a new question and link it here- need more info.

Comment: @tedder42, this is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43125253/amazon-ses-process-emails-stored-in-s3

Comment: Seems it is deprecated, Use `AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build()`

Comment: what is the "key" in  S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key)); ?

Answer (score 26):

In 2019 there's a bit more <s>optimal</s> robust way to read a file from S3:

```
private final AmazonS3 amazonS3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();

private Collection<String> loadFileFromS3() {
    try (final S3Object s3Object = amazonS3Client.getObject(BUCKET_NAME,
                                                            FILE_NAME);
        final InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(s3Object.getObjectContent(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader)) {
        return reader.lines().collect(Collectors.toSet());
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e)
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
}
```

Do note the comment about the memory usage of this piece of code.

Comment: Optimal in what way (good to clarify)?. This ends up pulling everything into memory and not using streaming semantics (fine if you have small files, bad if you have a 100GB file).

Comment: @PragmaticProgrammer it took me some time, but I modified the answer, thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 17):

We can also use `software.amazon.awssdk:s3`

```
 //Assuming the credentials are read from Environment Variables, so no hardcoding here

    S3Client client = S3Client.builder()
                        .region(regionSelected)
                        .build();
    
    GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .key(fileName)
                    .build();
    
    ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse> responseInputStream = client.getObject(getObjectRequest);

    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseInputStream.readAllBytes());
    
    
    System.out.println("Content :"+ new String(responseInputStream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: Note `InputStream.readAllBytes()` is available from Java 9

Comment: @hertzsprung Thanks for pointing that out ! Yup I was using Java 11 as far I remember

Comment: @hertzsprung, @
Abhishek Sengupta,            Is there any way to perform this same operation with Java 8?, using the maven dependency "as software.amazon.awssdk:s3"

Comment: @Sonu There are [alternatives to `InputStream.readAllBytes()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59049358/150884) for Java 8

Comment: ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> response = s3Client.getObject(getObjectRequest,ResponseTransformer.toBytes());

Answer (score 7):

Steps to read S3 file in java can be:

1. Create AmazonS3Client.
2. Create S3Object using bucket name and key.
3. Create buffer reader using S3Object and read file line by line.

1 >>>

```
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey", "secretKey");
    AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
            .withRegion("region_name_here").build();
```

2 >>>

```
   S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("bucketName", "key"));
```

3 >>>

```
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(object.getObjectContent()));

    String s = null;
    while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
        //your business logic here
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If the file's content is a string, then you can use [getObjectAsString](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#getObjectAsString-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). Otherwise, you can use [IOUtils.toByteArray](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/util/IOUtils.html#toByteArray-java.io.InputStream-) on `getObjectContent()` to read the file's content into a byte array.

Obviously, these are best used on small-ish S3 objects that will easily fit into memory.

```
private final AmazonS3 amazonS3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();

private String loadStringFromS3() {
    try {
        return amazonS3Client.getObjectAsString(BUCKET_NAME, FILE_NAME);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e)
        return null;
    }
}

private byte[] loadDataFromS3() {
    try (final S3Object s3Object = amazonS3Client.getObject(BUCKET_NAME, FILE_NAME)) {
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(s3Object.getObjectContent());
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e)
        return null;
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(object, log);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution. I'm using spring boot 2.4.3

Create an **amazon s3 client**

```
AmazonS3 amazonS3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withRegion("your-region")
                .withCredentials(
                        new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                            new BasicAWSCredentials("your-access-key", "your-secret-access-key")))
                .build();
```

Create an **amazon transfer client**.

```
TransferManager transferManagerClient = TransferManagerBuilder.standard()
                .withS3Client(amazonS3Client)
                .build();
```

Create a *temporary file* in **/tmp/{your-s3-key}** so that we can put the file we download in this file.

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "your-s3-key"); 

try {
    file.createNewFile(); // Create temporary file
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

file.mkdirs();  // Create the directory of the temporary file
```

Then, we download the file from s3 using **transfer manager client**

```
// Note that in this line the s3 file downloaded has been transferred in to the temporary file that we created
Download download = transferManagerClient.download(
               new GetObjectRequest("your-s3-bucket-name", "your-s3-key"), file); 

// This line blocks the thread until the download is finished
download.waitForCompletion();
```

Now that the s3 file has been successfully transferred into the *temporary file* that we created. We can get the InputStream of the *temporary file*.

```
InputStream input = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
```

Because the *temporary file* is not needed anymore, we just delete it.

```
file.delete();
```

Comment: Hey blue sky, can you explain what this code is doing?

Comment: @bsheps I just edited my answer, how about that?

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to do it as of 2023:

```
  public Long downloadFile(S3TransferManager transferManager, String bucketName,
                             String key, String downloadedFileWithPath) {
        DownloadFileRequest downloadFileRequest =
                DownloadFileRequest.builder()
                        .getObjectRequest(b -> b.bucket(bucketName).key(key))
                        .addTransferListener(LoggingTransferListener.create())
                        .destination(Paths.get(downloadedFileWithPath))
                        .build();

        FileDownload downloadFile = transferManager.downloadFile(downloadFileRequest);

        CompletedFileDownload downloadResult = downloadFile.completionFuture().join();
        log.info("Content length [{}]", downloadResult.response().contentLength());
        return downloadResult.response().contentLength();
    }
```

Comment: How do you check the download completed successfully using CompletedFileDownload?

Comment: Check the `downloadResult.response()` method

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JDK 1.8 or later and Java NIO then you can make use of the `aws-java-nio-spi-for-s3` package which provides a drop-in SPI that will allow Java to read and write S3 objects using standard Java Paths, Channels etc.

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-java-nio-spi-for-s3

Answer (score 0):

The solution shown by @ACV is the one proposed by AWS in their [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/transfer-manager.html#transfer-manager-download)

It's important to add how to control this part of the code is successful:

```
CompletedFileDownload downloadResult = downloadFile.completionFuture().join();
```

How do you control download was successful and check errors?

```
try {
    CompletedFileDownload downloadResult = fileDownload.completionFuture().join();
    System.out.println("Successfully downloaded file with content length: " + downloadResult.response().contentLength());
    return downloadResult.response().contentLength(); //You decide what to return
} catch(CancellationException e) {
    System.out.println("File download was cancelled");
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch(CompletionException e) {
    System.out.println("File download completed with error");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return -1; //Some error occurred
```