# Java 1.8 and below equivalent for InputStream.readAllBytes()

Tags: java, java-8, inputstream

I wrote a program that gets all bytes from an `InputStream` in **Java 9** with

```
InputStream.readAllBytes()
```

Now, I want to export it to **Java 1.8 and below**. Is there an equivalent function? Couldn't find one.

Comment: [`InputStream.readAllBytes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes--) is since Java 9+

Comment: Usually when someone wants to do this, it’s an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  Why do you need all of the bytes in memory?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's one way to solve this without relying on third-party libraries:

```
inputStream.reset();
byte[] bytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
dataInputStream.readFully(bytes);
```

Or if you don't mind using thirdparties (Commons IO):

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
```

Guava also helps:

```
byte[] bytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(inputStream);
```

Comment: In case of a `File`, you can use [`Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath())`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)) (since Java 7).

Comment: so how to convert dataInputStream into bytes again?

Comment: the first solution here supposes we're reading a file, which is not what the OP has asked for. It should be updated to reset and use "available" instead of the length.

Comment: Not all input streams support `reset()`, nor `available()`. Overall, is consider it a bad idea to edit an answer marked as solving the question.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the good old [`read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) method like this:

```
   public static byte[] readAllBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    final int bufLen = 1024;
    byte[] buf = new byte[bufLen];
    int readLen;
    IOException exception = null;

    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        while ((readLen = inputStream.read(buf, 0, bufLen)) != -1)
            outputStream.write(buf, 0, readLen);

        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        exception = e;
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (exception == null) inputStream.close();
        else try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            exception.addSuppressed(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since your method was not responsible for opening the `InputStream` it should not be closing it—that responsibility is left to the caller.

Comment: @Slaw that's true. It was only to cover up all the topics. Also, what if the caller in-lines it? in that case you have to close it from within the method.

Comment: It is the responsibility of the code that opened the resource (or requested some other code to open the resource on its behalf) to manage the resource (i.e. close it when finished). Your method did not open the resource which means it's not the method's responsibility to manage it. If the caller opened the resource but fails to close it then that's a bug which must be fixed by the caller. Besides, what if the caller doesn't want to close the resource immediately? Your method takes away the caller's control in that regard.

Comment: Of course, you could design the method to close the resource but it must be documented to do so. I'd also expect a name more akin to `readAllBytesAndClose`.

Comment: If you want to close the incoming `InputStream`, just use try-with-resource, `try(InputStream toClose = inputStream) { ... }`. You may even combine it with the already existing try-with-resource statement.

Comment: @Holger what if you are using JDK less than 1.7?

Comment: Your answer is already using the try-with-resource statement, as well as calling `addSuppressed` in the manual handling, so that's a pointless question. If you want to support even older Java versions, the code has to look entirely different anyway.