# Read N Lines from S3 in Java using aws-java-sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

How to Read 100 lines at a time of a CSV file from s3 using aws sdk.
In below code i am reading single line at a time.

```
S3Object o  = s3Client.getObject("temp", "file_name");
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(o.getObjectContent());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String s = null;
            while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(s);
                //your business logic here
            }
            inputStreamReader.close();
```

Is there any way to read 100 or 1000 line at a time.

Answer (score 2):

For file with small size, Amazon provides [getObjectAsString](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#getObjectAsString-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). You can try as

```
String objAsString  = s3Client.getObjectAsString("temp", "file_name");
```

what it does is

> Retrieves and decodes the contents of an S3 object to a String.

You can also use `lines()` and collect to a `List<String>` after getting `BufferedReader reader`

```
reader.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can refer to some other ways [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568635/read-aws-s3-file-to-java-code)